# How to size images loaded from other users such that dimensions are maintained yet a max width and height are set with css? (HTML/JS/CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I want to know how, within say a div element, I can load an image from an API (where the user may post whatever size image they want) and I can then format that image to meet the following requirements with CSS.
1) the original dimensions are maintained

2) given a max width and max height that I specify, the attribute of the image out of my control that differs greatest from the corresponding attribute in my specification will be shrunk down to match it, with the other attribute shrinking to maintain dimension.  If the image is in fact smaller on both dimensions than my specifications than the dimension of the image that differs the LEAST from its corresponding specification should grow to match it, with the other one again moving to maintain dimension.

3) The image should center itself in it's parent node depending on whether it is the width or the height specification that is not maxed out (ie: if max_width was 200px and images width was only 180 then it should center itself along the x axis).

I suppose I could do it with JS, but I imagine its a common enough desire that there is an easier way to do it than logically inputting it.  (Also how with JS can I get access to the height and width attributes of the user uploaded images coming in from the JSON file, and how in JS can I center an image within it's parent node?):

JS/Pseudo code mix looks like this, but I want to know how to do it in CSS if possible:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxHeight = whateEverWeSpecify;
    var maxWidth = whateverWeSpecify;
    $.getJSON('jsonFileWithPropertyImagePointingToUserUploadedImage', formatImg);
  });
function formatImg(json){
 var div  document.createElement('div');
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 img.setAttribute('src', json.image);
 **//this is the part   I dont know how to read dimensions of** incoming image so ill use img.height and width.height to refer to dimensions of incoming JSON img here 
 var heightDifference = img.height - maxHeight;
 var widthDifference = img.width - maxWidth;
 if (widthDifference < 0 && heightDifference < 0){
   if (heightDifference < widthDifference){
     img.style.height = img.height + heightDifference;
   } 
   else{
     img.style.width = img.width + widthDifference;
   }
 }
 else{
  if (heightDifference > widthDifference){
    img.style.height = img.height - heightDifference
  }
  else{
    img.style.width = img.width - widthDifference
  }
  /*sizes are adjusted to fit specifications at this point.  I have no idea 
  how to center the image along the y or x axis depending on which one is 
  required other than that we can determine which to change based on which 
  attributes difference from the specification is greater than 0 (in 
  essence, which attribute was updated), so if you could help me with this 
  too for future reference I would greatly appreciate it */
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a div with the 'background-image' property, and use 'background-size:contain'.

I had this same kind of problem when trying to handle profile pictures in a dating website I was building.  You never know if the user is gonna upload a tall or wide picture.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="image_container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    background:lightgray;
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
}
.image_container {
    position:relative;
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    left:10%;
    top:10%;
    background-image:url('http://icatcare.org/sites/default/files/kcfinder/images/images/aggressive-cat_0.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-color:darkgray;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Here's the codepen.  Un-comment the second background-image line to see how this works with a tall image:  [centered background image](http://codepen.io/midgitsuu/pen/LGgWmy).

I put a darker grey background on the inner div just to show you that the div stays at the proportions you set, the CSS handles images of varying sizes within.  This solution at least keeps your layout from floating or wrapping oddly based on changing image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an `<img>` tag. Instead, use the `background-image` property in CSS. This gives you access to `background-size:contain;`, which will do exactly what you're talking about.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

For example:

```
<style>
  .userpic{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
</style>

<div class="userpic" style="background-image:url(myimage.jpg)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will not need this anymore but... to get the original dimensions of the image:

```
var imgWidth = img.naturalWidth;
var imgHeight = img.naturalHeight;
```

The answers before me pretty much solved the adjusting image problem with css... except for the code to put the image into the container's background via javascript:

```
function formatImg(json){

    var node = document.getElementById('yourNodeId'); // This is the node where you want to put the image (a div maybe, or the document's body)
    var div = document.createElement('div'); // This will be the image's container
    div.classList.add('image_container');
    div.style.backgroundImage = "url(json.image)";

    node.appendChild(div);
    }
```

Just add the styles mentioned before me and problem solved